# Forcing input parameters in QGIS processing scripts?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

Is there any way to force input parameters (e.g. data provider, geometry type, field type) in processing scripts?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you attempted thus far?

Comment: are you familiar with the [Graphical Modeller](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/ca/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html)? Or do you need fields to be made mandatory/required outside of the modeller, e.g. running a single algorithm from a Python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **processing scripts**, I don't think it is currently possible to filter out a layer's **data provider** specifically for PostGIS layers. Looking at the [parameters.py](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/core/parameters.py) file for the processing framework, it seems that you can only specify the following for all loaded shapefiles:

- Geometry type: (point, line or polygon)
- Field type: (number, string)

So currently, you could use something like:

```
##Input table=vector point
##Distance field=field number Input table
```

---

You could try and edit the file to include a PostGIS parameter (not sure how much editing is required) which you can find in your QGIS directory. E.g.:

```
C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.18.2/apps/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/parameters.py
```